# No cargan Datos en el formulario al editar; Angular

Tags: angular

soy nueva en angular y necesito ayuda por favor, quiero editar los atributos de un Libro en especifico de una lista de libros, pero no se me cargan los valores en cada input del formulario, pero si aparece en consola, es decir no asigna los valores a los inputs de mi formulario
Estoy utilizando el FormGroup para guardar los datos y quiero hacer lo mismo para editarlos

libroForm.Component

```
 Miformulario: FormGroup;
 libro:Libro=new Libro();

 ngOnInit() {

  let aux= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("cuenta"));
   this.Miformulario= this.fb.group({
    isbn:[''],
    titulo:[''],
    stock:[],
    precioUnitario:[],
    descripcion:[''],
    autores:this.fb.array([this.fb.group({nombre:['']})]),
    generos:this.fb.array([this.fb.group({nombre:['']})]),
    editoriales:this.fb.array([this.fb.group({nombre:['']})]),     
    cuenta:aux.idCuenta,     
  });

  this.cargar();

 }

 onSubmit(formValue: any){ 

 const libro= new Libro();

  libro.isbn=formValue.isbn;

   libro.titulo=formValue.titulo;
   libro.stock=formValue.stock;
   libro.precioUnitario=formValue.precioUnitario;
   libro.descripcion=formValue.descripcion;   
   libro.autores=formValue.autores;
   libro.generos=formValue.generos;
   libro.editoriales=formValue.editoriales;
   libro.cuenta.idCuenta=formValue.cuenta;

this.libroservice.uploadImg(this.imagen,libro.isbn).subscribe(
  data=>{
    this.spinner.hide();
    this.libroservice.createLi(libro).subscribe
      (resp=>this.router.navigate(['/lista']));
    //this.router.navigate(['/lista']);
  },
  err=>{
    this.spinner.hide();
    Swal.fire('Alerta',`Imagen No subida`, 'warning' );
    this.reset();
  }
);
}

cargar():void{

   this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
     b=>{
      let id = b['id'];
      if(id){
       this.libroservice.get(id).subscribe(
         (ac=>{this.libro=ac;console.log(ac)}));
      }})
     }

               get getnombreautor(){
                 return this.Miformulario.get('autores') as 
               FormArray;
                    }

      addnombreAutor(){
          const control= 
      <FormArray>this.Miformulario.controls['autores'];
         control.push(this.fb.group({nombre:[]}));
       }

        removeAutor(index:number){
          const control= 
          <FormArray>this.Miformulario.controls['autores'];
             control.removeAt(index);
         }
```

SERVICE

```
   createLi(libros:Libro):Observable<Libro>{
     return this.http.post<Libro>(this.url,libros)
   }

 get(isbn:string):Observable<Libro>{
     return this.http.get<Libro>(this.url+'/id/'+isbn);
  }
```

HTML

```
           <form   class="col-8"[formGroup]="Miformulario" 
            (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(Miformulario.value)"  novalidate 
                       enctype="multipart/form-data">
        
                   <div class="mb-3">
                         <label for="stock" class="form-label">Stock</label>
                         <input type="number" class="form-control"  id="stock" 
                     formControlName="stock">
                  </div> 
              <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="precioUnitario" class="form-label">Precio Unitario</label>
                   <input type="number" class="form-control"  id="precioUnitario" 
                    formControlName="precioUnitario" >
              </div>
             
          
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="autor" class="form-label">Genero(s)</label>
                <div formArrayName="generos">
                    <div *ngFor="let item of getGeneros.controls; let pointIndex=index" 
                   [formGroupName]="pointIndex">
                      <input formControlName="nombre" type="text" class="form-control" 
              id="nombre"><a class=" boton menos btn btn-link" (click)="removeGenero(pointIndex)"></a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <a class=" boton mas btn btn-link" (click)="addGenero()"></a>
               </div> 

   </form>
```

No entiendo por que no funciona en el console.log si se muestra el libro, solamente en los inputs no cargan los datos. el routerlink que abre el formulario para editar segun el Id del libro funciona bien, entonces ya no se que hacer, ayuda por favor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola Esther puedes probar como primer paso.
Donde recuperas la data de libro lo siguiente.

```
if(id){
       this.libroservice.get(id).subscribe(
         (ac=>{
this.libro = ac;
this.Miformulario.patchValue({
    isbn:[ac.isbn],
    titulo:[ac.titulo],
    stock:[ac.stock],
    precioUnitario:[ac.precioUnitario] // De momento con los campos sencillos
})
console.log(ac)}

));
      }})
 }
```

Prueba a ver si ahora te rellena los los inputs.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, efectivamente me ayudo con estos datos

Comment: y como seria con los campos que son array como autores?

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la parte compleja, por que me puedo imaginar, autores habrá uno o más.
No se si lo tienes en un string guardado en la base de datos.

```
this.autores = JSON.parse(ac.autores.replace(/false/gi, "\"\""));
this.rellenarFormularios('autores', this.autores );

rellenarFormularios( field, value) {
  let keys: any = [];
  let formdiff = this.Miformulario.get(field) as FormArray;
  
  let formularioGrupo: FormGroup;  
  for (let index = 0; index < value.length; index++) {
    formularioGrupo = new FormGroup({});
    const element = value[index];
    for (const key in element) {
      keys[index] = key;    
     formularioGrupo.addControl(key, new FormControl(element[key]) );

  
  }
 formdiff.push(formularioGrupo); //me faltaba esta línea }
```

Espero que te sirva, si no fuera así no dudes en preguntar.

Comment: muchas gracias, lo que no entiendo es que utilizando ```this.Miformulario.patchValue({
    isbn:[ac.isbn],
    titulo:[ac.titulo],
    stock:[ac.stock],
    precioUnitario:[ac.precioUnitario],
     autores:[console.log(ac.autores[0].nombre)]   }) ``` autores  si se me imprime en consola, pero cuando pongo lo mismo: ```autores:[ac.autores[0].nombre ``` en esta forma, no se cargan en el input

Comment: los datos vienen desde una base de datos y se pueden aumentar con inputs dinamicos

Comment: Tendría que verlo, por que me imagino que pueden que los datos ya vengan en formato json o en formato stringfy y pasarlo a json. En este caso el método rellenarFormularios serían 3 campos para contemplaren campo nombre  a rellenar.